# In CPanel, cron job is not being executing and not sending any mail

Tags: email, gmail, php, cron, cpanel

though many of us has asked many question related to cron jobs, let me ask my one...

I want to execute a PHP script periodically.  As a cron command I'm using:

```
php -q http://www.example.com/cron.php?action=getA
```

I also tried this one:

```
php -q /home/myuser/www.example.com/cron.php?action=getA
```

It is not getting executed and not sending any mail.  I set the mail ID to my **gMail ID**.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you execute the script directly is the mail sent?

Comment: In CPanel there is an option to set an email id.

`Send an email every time a cron job runs. less »

You can have cron send an email everytime it runs a command. If you do not want an email to be sent for an individual cron job you can redirect the command's output to /dev/null like this: mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1 

Current Email: mygmailid@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting will not work as you cannot pass GET variables via the PHP command line and you need to either escape question marks or surround the string with quotes when using question marks on the command line.

This will work:

`wget 'http://www.example.com/cron.php?action=getA'`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
wget http://www.example.com/cron.php?action=getA
```

are you sure you have www.example.com as your path?

execute the following in your cron.php

```
<?php
// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";
?>
```

This will return you the exact directory where your cron.php file is located, and the use php -q in your cron.

I think you should use something as this on cPanel:

```
php -q /home/myuser/public_html/cron.php?action=getA
```

Comment: I have tried "wget http://www.example.com/cron.php?action=getA" this one also.
But no mails. :(

Comment: Execute the line to get the folder path. And then include it with PHP -q

Comment: u meant to say "php -q /home/myuser/pathtocronfile/cron.php"?
I tried that. :(
Please elaborately reply.

Comment: As cron commands i tried this one:

wget /home/myuser/public_html/cron.php;
php -q /home/ovsec/public_html/cron.php

it is not working. Please help.